# A variant of Dijkstra algorithm based on restricted paths

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, graph-traversal

Given a graph =(,), a source node ∈, and a subset ′⊆ of labeled edges, I want to find all restricted shortest paths between  and the rest of nodes where any restricted path is only allowed to contain at most one labeled edge in ′.

How can we extend Dijkstra algorithm to efficiently solve this problem?

Comment: It would be better to explain your question using an example.

Comment: Sounds like homework to me.